# Namespaces/packages names with Python's C extensions

Tags: python, distutils, python-c-extension

I'm learning/experimenting with Python extensions in C. I'm trying to wrap a C library such that it can be used in a more Pythonic way. For example:

```
import mylib

widget = mylib.widget.Widget(name="Hello!")
widget.show()

mylib.utils.say_hello()
```

In the C code, the name of the module passed to `PyModule_Create` is "mylib", "mylib.widget", and "mylib.utils" respectively. The `mylib.widget` module includes a new `Widget` type as well.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to get these extensions to install with that style of package/namespace. I tried:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
    ...
    ext_modules = [Extension('mylib', sources=['src/mylib.c'], ...), 
                   Extension('mylib.widget', sources=['src/widget.c'], ...),
                   Extension('mylib.utils', sources=['src/utils.c'], ...)]
)
```

But that doesn't work. "mylib has no module named widget".

How are C extensions generally packaged/distributed?

Comment: Do you have a valid mylib package? i.e. mylib directory with \_\_init\_\_.py file

Answer (score 1):

Extensions can have child modules but you probably have to define them in the C init() function; distutils, as you saw, gave up the ghost at the very concept. I would do something like this instead:

```
from distutils.core import setup,Extension

setup(
  packages = ['package_name'],
  ext_modules = [
    Extension('package_name.widget',sources=['src/widget.c']),
    Extension('package_name.utils',sources=['src/utils.c'])
  ]
)
```

And then have your file layout be:

```
ROOT/
 | -- setup.py
 | -- src/
 |     | -- widget.c
 |     | -- utils.c
 | -- package_name/
 |     | -- __init__.py
 |     | -- (other python files)
```

This way your `*.so` files (or `*.pyd` on windows) will end up inside a `package_name/` directory in your python site-packages.